# Mysql Select group similar rows from two table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'd really appreciate it if someone could help me for my problem.

I've got that two mysql table:

**Cities ( about 90.000 rows )**

```
|         ID(primaryKey)         |  CITY_ID |  SUPPLIER   |
|3fe07eaec62d209c1c153bd3e5501ac5|  xxxxxx  |  supplier1  |
|2a3eaad85c0e7ebb1f7ddaf9a423d808|  yyyyyy  |  supplier2  |
|c47376be023028eb17addcd5813cf592|  zzzzzz  |  supplier3  |
|f4d2b3a0da4d6bad0c89ad2471bd1dd7|  kkkkkk  |  supplier1  |
```

**City_Translates ( about 500.000 rows )**

```
|               ID               |  CITY    |  COUNTRY        | LANGUAGE |
|3fe07eaec62d209c1c153bd3e5501ac5|  LONDRA  |  Gran Bretagna  |    IT    |
|3fe07eaec62d209c1c153bd3e5501ac5|  LONDON  |  Great Britain  |    EN    |
|3fe07eaec62d209c1c153bd3e5501ac5|  LONDON  |  Großbritannien |    DE    |
|c47376be023028eb17addcd5813cf592|  LONDON  |  Great Britain  |    EN    |
|c47376be023028eb17addcd5813cf592|  LONDRA  |  Gran Bretagna  |    EN    |
|2a3eaad85c0e7ebb1f7ddaf9a423d808|  ROMA    |  ITALIA         |    IT    |
|2a3eaad85c0e7ebb1f7ddaf9a423d808|  ROME    |  ITALY          |    EN    |
```

What i need is to create a php script to group these two table in order to have a structure like this:

```
[
{"translates":
  {
    "it":{"city":"LONDRA","country":"Gran Bretagna"},
    "en":{"city":"LONDON","country":"Great Bretain"},
    "de":{"city":"LONDON","country":"Großbritannien"}
  },
 "suppliers":
  {
     "supplier1":"xxxxxx",
     "supplier2":"zzzzzz"
  }
},
{"translates":
  {
    "it":{"city":"ROMA","country":"ITALIA"},
    "en":{"city":"ROME","country":"ITALY"}
  },
 "suppliers":
  {
     "supplier1":"yyyyyy"
  }
},...]
```

I do this because i need to import that structure into a noSQL database so this operation must be done just one time.

Can someone give me a solution?

Thanks!

Comment: In your example, why is `$array[0]->suppliers->supplier2` listed? It looked like everything in the first record was related to ID `3fe07eaec62d209c1c153bd3e5501ac5`

Comment: no.. that was just an example.. i need to group for city and country for each language

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused as to why `LONDON/Great Britain` are referencing different city IDs (the primary keys). Anyway I assume you want to group by a combination of the city string  and city id (pk) because your example has multiple suppliers per group.

i.e. We know that `LONDON` and `LONDRA` belong to the same group because they have the same key. When they're seen again with different keys we know they belong to same group because we have encountered those city names before.

Here's a shot :)

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM Cities c 
JOIN City_Translates ct ON ct.ID = c.ID
ORDER BY ID"; //order by is necessary so all like cities end up in the same group

$rs = mysqli_query($query) or die(mysqli_error());

$results = array();
$city_id = array(); // lookup id by city name
//used to group like cities

while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs)) {

    //if we've seen this city before grab
    //the city id (pk) where we store its data
    if(isset($city_id[$r['CITY']])) {
        $id = $city_id[$r['CITY']];
    }
    else { //otherwise store the city id (pk) for this city
        $city_id[$r['CITY']] = $r['ID'];
        $id = $r['ID'];
    }

    $results[$id]['translates'][$r['LANGUAGE']] = array(
        'city' => $r['CITY'],
        'country' => $r['COUNTRY'],
    );

    $results[$id]['suppliers'][$r['SUPPLIER']] = $r['CITY_ID']; 
}

$results = array_values($results); //remove ID keys
print json_encode($results,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```